# Transitions of the process to different states

Tags: c

Suppose I have a simple c program.I want to know the transitions this program makes that is if it goes into a blocked state or suspended state etc.,as it is getting executed.Can someone please explain taking a simple c program and going through the transitions for each line of code?

Comment: Suggest you supply a code example as your question is rather vague

Answer (score 2):

States are applicable to processes. A program under execution is referred to as a process.
This link would be a better way to understand different states of a process
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_state